# Windows. Сервер БД MySQL 8.0. Ошибка входа в mysql-клиент

Tags: mysql, windows

Не могу войти в `mysql`-консоль на Windows!

**Ошибки входа:**

> **ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
> password: **YES/NO**)**

**Пароль для пользователя `root` задавался при инсталляции сервера.**

**В таблице `mysql.user` - только один пользователь `root`**

*Уже опробованы следующие способы входа:*

**СПОСОБ-1.** Простой вход в mysql-консоль командами: `mysql -u root` и `mysql -u root -p`

**СПОСОБ-2.** Смена пароля `root` с остановкой службы сервера `net stop mysql80`,с запуском в режиме отключенных grand-таблиц: `mysqld --skip-grant-tables --shared-memory`, запуском в другом терминале mysql-консоли: `mysql` и переустановкой пароля для `root`:

```
USE mysql;    
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;    
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NewPassword';
```

затем выход из консоли и снова запуск службы сервера БД: `net start mysql80`

**СПОСОБ-3.** Создание файла с настройками входа `mysql.ini`, содержащего:

```
[client]
user = root
password = "NewPassword"
host = localhost
```

и запуск его как

`"<path to MySQL>\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysql.exe" "--defaults-file=<path>\my.ini" "-uroot" "-p"`

**СПОСОБ-4.** Подключение MySQL в клиенте `DBeaver` с настройками:

```
allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
useSSL=false
```

- та же самая ошибка
  [image: скрин ошибки подключения клиента DBeaver к MySQL]

**СПОСОБ-5.** Использование плагина аутентификации с остановом сервера и режимом выключенных grand-таблиц:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'NewPassword';
```

> **РЕЗУЛЬТАТ**. У всех способов одна и та же ошибка доступа:
>
> ```
> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES/NO)
> ```

**ЛОГ ОШИБОК СЕРВЕРА - файл `<file>.err` за пару дней:**

```
2021-06-16T12:18:54.134010Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.24) initializing of server in progress as process 6308
2021-06-16T12:18:54.146008Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-16T12:18:55.061008Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-06-16T12:18:57.454009Z 6 [Note] [MY-010454] [Server] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: qgvw19g#b)kR
2021-06-16T12:19:16.101010Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.24) starting as process 9248
2021-06-16T12:19:16.122008Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-16T12:19:16.569008Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-06-16T12:19:16.739008Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011311] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'All I/O interfaces are disabled, X Protocol won't be accessible'
2021-06-16T12:19:16.922008Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-06-16T12:19:16.923008Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-06-16T12:19:16.954008Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.24'  socket: ''  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2021-06-17T11:09:47.627002Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.24) starting as process 2236
2021-06-17T11:09:47.694000Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-17T11:09:48.608000Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-06-17T11:09:48.967000Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011311] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'All I/O interfaces are disabled, X Protocol won't be accessible'
2021-06-17T11:09:49.020000Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
2021-06-17T11:09:49.032000Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
2021-06-17T11:09:49.113000Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-06-17T11:09:49.114000Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-06-17T11:09:49.371000Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.24'  socket: ''  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2021-06-17T11:19:53.451798Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.24) starting as process 6772
2021-06-17T11:19:53.548362Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-17T11:19:54.553112Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-06-17T11:19:54.760040Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011311] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'All I/O interfaces are disabled, X Protocol won't be accessible'
2021-06-17T11:19:54.802576Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
2021-06-17T11:19:54.812922Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
2021-06-17T11:19:54.858906Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-06-17T11:19:54.860056Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-06-17T11:19:54.892245Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.24'  socket: ''  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

**Bonus**

> Вместе с тем, вновь установленный выше означенными средствами пароль
> не принимается при попытке сконфигурировать сервер через инсталятор!

Перечитал половину интернета и `stackoverflow` и кроме этих вариантов не нахожу решений.

**Какие ещё настройки надо задействовать?**

Comment: А с плагином аутентификации всё в порядке? попробуй `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'NewPassword';`. И ещё - нет ли в mysql.user ещё одного `root` с другим хостом? `'%'`, `'127.0.0.1'`... аутентификация при попытке входа запросто может выполняться не той учёткой, на которую ты думаешь...

Comment: Таблицу `user` проверял - пользователь `root` в одном экземпляре.

Comment: Да, в качестве идиотских предположений - а нет ли чего особенного в пароле? скажем, символа доллара...

Comment: Нет, всё банально просто - только латинские символы. PS. Нормальное предположение, сейчас необходимо все варианты проверить.

Comment: Использование плагина аутентификации закончилось с тем же результатом `access denied`. Добавил в текст вопроса предложенный вариант в список опробованных .

Comment: Ещё - гляньте, что там пишется в Error Log, он должен дать побольше информации.

Comment: Добавил логи сервера в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась глуже. При запуске инсталлятора MySQL и попытке изменить конфигурацию модулей, вновь установленный вышеописанными методами пароль оказался не валидным.

В итоге снёс и установил заного, теперь проблем нет!